# best way to store HUGE hierarchy data into mysql database?

Tags: mysql, hierarchy, hierarchical-data

I need some help and have been reading online but couldn't find a solid answer to my issue. I don't know how to store my hierarchical data in my innoDB-table.

The potential hierarchy could be 200+ million nodes with 15-20 depths. Once the hierarchy database is created, there is no plan to write to it but only reading.

What can I use? Are there methods to parallel this as well?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4048151/what-are-the-options-for-storing-hierarchical-data-in-a-relational-database?rq=1

Comment: what are the technical requirements, such as 50000 ops/sec or grandma's huge recipe database, 1 read per week? user locations?